# woocommerce products size doesnt show full image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want when i upload a product the size must be added automaticlly.

```
Dashboard/Woocommerce/Products/
```

actually it doenst show full image in products/ when i upload feautered image 
here the [link](http://nikitekstil-ks.com)

Answer (score 0):

It is bcoz you are having a woocommerce setup. WooCommerce catalog settings is having a size, which is reflecting in woocommerce product page.

You can modify woocommerce template to show actual image size. But it is not recommended.

Because, if you upload images for different product with different images, you site make look unorganized.

Comment: Aha i only need the product image to be fullwidth,i thought i can find a plugin that may help me out